# Copy data from old HD to Mac

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hfs

I've got an old 3 1/2 '' IDE HD, with a FAT32 and a HFS+ partition, and I'd like to copy the data to a Macbook. However, the old HD casing that I used it with is broken, and the new casing I bought (Sweex) doesn't work - the drive doesn't spin up. I can plug it into a PC and hear it spin up, so it's not broken.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

There are [some very inexpensive options](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=usb+hard+drive+adapter&num=10&hl=en&newwindow=1&client=firefox-a&hs=J5X&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=ivs&resnum=3&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=5266498069522446691&ei=CPnKTNfmCYnAsAPls6GNDg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CH4Q8wIwAw#) if you only want to get the data off the drive and don't plan on using it daily in that configuration.